# memory-leak AffineTransformOp

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I tried to create a class that contains a BufferedImage and can rotate itself. However if I try to access it in a loop out of a temporary main method, it creates a memory-leak and I can't figure out whats responsibly for it.

```
public class PImage
{
private BufferedImage image;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static Class ressourceClass = PImage.class;

public PImage(BufferedImage setImage)
{
    image = setImage;
}

public PImage(String name)
{
    load(name , "png");
}

private void load(String name , String extension)
{
    String path = "/" + name + "." + extension;

    try
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(ressourceClass.getResource(path));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("PImage: Ladefehler. " + path + " existiert nicht.");
    }
}

public PImage newRotate(double angle)
{
    angle = angle % (2 * Math.PI);

    int newHeight = 1 + (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(image.getWidth() , 2) + Math.pow(image.getHeight() , 2));
    int newWidth = 1 + (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(image.getWidth() , 2) + Math.pow(image.getHeight() , 2));

    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth , newHeight , BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();
    AffineTransformOp rotateOP;

    affineTransform.translate((newWidth - image.getWidth()) / 2 , (newHeight - image.getHeight()) / 2);
    affineTransform.rotate(angle , image.getWidth() / 2 , image.getHeight() / 2);
    rotateOP = new AffineTransformOp(affineTransform , AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    newImage = rotateOP.filter(image , newImage);

    return new PImage(newImage);
}

public void rotate(double angle)
{
    image = newRotate(angle).getImage();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PImage i = new PImage("test");

    while (true)
    {
        i.rotate(0.1);
    }
}
```